# How to call a function object differently, depending on its arity (or other information known at compile time)?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, arity

In a function template, I'd like to call a function, or function object differently, depending on its arity (how many arguments it takes). In pseudocode:

```
if arity(f) == 1:
    f(x)
if arity(f) == 2:
    f(x, y)
if arity(f) == 3:
    f(x, y, z)
```

How can this be done in C++?

**Edit** To clarify the difficulty: `f(x, y, z)` won't compile if `f` only takes 2 arguments, and vice versa, `f(x, y)` won't compile when `f` needs 3 arguments.

Comment: Put the arguments `x,y,z` into a tuple and expand that tuple based on arity (see Dieter Lücking's answer for how to get the arity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C++11:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename F> struct Traits;

template <typename R, typename... A>
struct Traits<R (A...)>
{
    static constexpr unsigned Arity = sizeof...(A);
};

void f(int, int, int);

int main() {
    std::cout
        << Traits<void()>::Arity
        << Traits<void(int)>::Arity
        << Traits<void(int, int)>::Arity
        << Traits<decltype(f)>::Arity
        << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise you might lookup boost::function: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/doc/html/function.html

Comment: Impressive, but your example doesn't **call** `f`.

Comment: @MaxB Sure - you need a dispatch mechanism to call f - which can not be an if(...) dispatch(first_function_type), else if(...) dispatch(second_function_type) ...