# Generate a std::tuple from standard container

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-mpl

Is there a portable way to generate a `std::tuple` (really a `std::array`) from the contents of a container? Such a tuple would allow `std::apply` to extract function arguments from a container.

My first attempt, using tail recursion, fails with compiler error: "recursive template instantiation exceeds maximum...".

I could not quite get my second attempt (`std::for_each` with a mutable lambda holding tuple) to compile with desired results.

I assume that something along the lines of how `boost::mpl` handles variadic metafunctions (ie magic using `boost::preprocessor`) could be made to work -- but that's so c++03. I'm hoping there's a better solution.

The function signature would look something like:

```
std::list<int> args_as_list = {1, 2, 3, 4};
auto tpl = args_as_tuple(args_as_list);
```

where type of `tpl` is `std::array<int const, 4>`.

Comment: *std::tuple (really a std::array)* what do you mean by that? std::uple and std::array are *not* the same.

Comment: Tuple is a compile time thing, you can't tell at compile time how much elem will be in the list. Anyways you can use the std::llist<T>::value_type

Comment: A `std::array` supports  `std::tuple` interface. Obviously all elements in the container are the same type `container::value_type`. So a true tuple, or a `std::array` are both fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **no**, it is not possible.

Explanation: both `std::tuple` and `std::array` require *compile-time* information about number of elements. `std::list` or `std::vector` can provide only *runtime* information about elements count.

your `args_as_tuple` function would have to be a template, taking number of expected arguments as template argument (`args_as_tuple<4>(args_as_list)`).

Although having to put number of arguments as template argument seems harsh, but in case of your example it's is quite obvious - number of function arguments (function provided to `std::apply`) has to be known on compile-time as well.
For more generic code you could use: [function-traits](https://github.com/kennytm/utils/blob/master/traits.hpp) or code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349158/how-to-call-a-function-object-differently-depending-on-its-arity-or-other-info).
Or use `std::array` from begging instead of `std::list` (a lot of generic template code, but good compile time checks)

Answer (score 1):

The number of elements in a `std::tuple`, or a `std::array`, is part of its type information. Therefore, your function `args_as_tuple` proposed above would have to be a template somehow, and each different possible size of the result is going to require a different instantiation of that template. Therefore, you cannot make a program that can support arbitrarily many sizes of tuples unless the code of that program is infinite (not possible).

If you only care about the range of values of `int`, say, you could instantiate the template 4 billion times, but then your executable is going to be at least 4 gigabytes large.

If you really only care about *a few* different sizes of vectors in your actual program, you could instantiate just those templates and write conversion code that cases out on the value of `std::list::size()` and calls the appropriate function (tedious).

But your exact code snippet

```
std::list<int> args_as_list = {1, 2, 3, 4};
auto tpl = args_as_tuple(args_as_list);
```

can *never work* in C++. Because, in C++ all variables have to have a known type determined at compile time. Even though you are using keyword `auto`, that `auto` has to get resolved at compile time to a fixed type, which means a fixed size if it's a tuple or array, no matter what sort of template shenanigans the expression `args_as_tuple` is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Since my problem can't be solved, I solved a slightly different one which allowed me to move on.

I came up with a solution which allows me to extract arguments for a functor from a container. I am able to instantiate a `eval_container` with the functor I want evaluated, then pass the container to the resulting object.

```
#include <utility>

template <int N>
using Int = std::integral_constant<int, N>;

template <typename T>
struct arity : arity<decltype(&T::operator())> {};

template <typename T, typename RT, typename...Args>
struct arity<RT(T::*)(Args...) const>
{
    // could enforce maximum number of arguments
    static constexpr int value = sizeof...(Args);
};

template <typename F, int N = arity<F>::value>
struct eval_container
{
    eval_container(F const& f) : f(f) {}
    eval_container(F&& f) : f(std::move(f)) {}

    template <typename Iter, typename I, typename...Args>
    auto operator()(Iter&& iter, I, Args&&...args) const
    {
        // assert(iter != end)
        auto&& arg = *iter++;
        return (*this)(std::forward<Iter>(iter)
                     , Int<I()-1>{}
                     , std::forward<Args>(args)...
                     , arg);
    }

    template <typename Iter, typename...Args>
    auto operator()(Iter&&, Int<0>, Args&&...args) const
    {
        // assert(iter == end)
        return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    template <typename C>
    auto operator()(C const& container) const
    {
        return (*this)(container.begin(), Int<N>{});
    }

    F f;
};
```

}